# How can one object belong to/have two users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, model-associations, single-table-inheritance

I have a User Model and a Favor Model. Users can ask for favors from other users or they can publish a favor saying that they are available if anyone needs a favor.

My question here is what is the best way to set up the relationship so that one Favor object can belong to/have two Users, one asking for a favor and one doing the favor?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If I were implementing this, I would make the `Favor` model `belongs_to` two `Users`, on two different properties. For example, you could have `favor_from` and `favor_to`  properties (each simply relationships to a `User`).

This frees you from dealing with figuring out which user is which. If necessary, you could even use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship for both properties - which would allow you to have one `Favor` belong to multiple Users. Then, a favor could be offered by multiple users, or multiple users could receive a favor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect naming for properties. And how would you suggest I save the ids to `favor_from` and `favor_to`?

Currently I have 
`<%= link_to 'Publish a Favor', new_favour_path(favor_from: current_user.id)`

`<%= link_to 'Ask a Favor', new_favour_path(favor_to: current_user.id)`

Comment: @fardin You probably want to do some validation on the back end to make sure a user can't publish a favor on behalf of another user - take out the parameter in the path generator, and just reference `current_user` in the controller.

Comment: I'll definitely do that, but again in create action how do I know whether the current user is doing or getting the favor? I feel like there is an obvious answer to this question and I can't figure it out :D

Comment: @fardin I'd just create two actions, one for creating an offered favor and one for creating a requested favor.

Answer (score 1):

Have the `User` model `has_many` `favors` and the `Favor` can `belong_to` `User`.

The naming can be better but here's the gist of it:

```
class Favor
  belongs_to :favor_asker, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :favor_doer, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  has_many :asked_favors, class_name: 'Favor'
  has_many :done_favors, class_name: 'Favor'
end
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? I have used this and know it works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. At this stage I can't even vote because I haven't earned 15 reputations! I'm a newbie :)